# Couchbase N1QL join query- syntax error

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I wanna join two buckets by below query. But it throws me an error like below. What am I missing?

**Error:**

```
syntax error - at ebook_id
```

**Query:**

```
 SELECT ebook_id, COUNT(*) as count 
        FROM `log` USE KEYS `log.`ebook_id 
        JOIN `product` USE KEYS product.book_id
        WHERE meta(`log`).id LIKE 'ebook_page_request%' AND `log`.date = CLOCK_LOCAL('1111-11-11') GROUP BY log.ebook_id
```

Comment: This looks like a typo? Check the placement of your backticks around `log` in the `FROM` clause

Answer (score 2):

```
 FROM `log` USE KEYS `log.`ebook_id
```

The back tick location is incorrect it needs to end before dot Like below

```
FROM `log` USE KEYS `log`.ebook_id
```

USE KEYS on LEFT side of JOIN needs to be CONSTANT and right of side of JOIN can't use USE KEYS and it must be ON KEYS with expression referring from left side bucket

[ANSI JOINS are supported only in CB 5.50](https://blog.couchbase.com/ansi-join-support-n1ql/)

[Pre CB 5.50 supports LOOKUP and Index Joins](https://dzone.com/articles/visually-explaining-n1ql-joins)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's usually not necessary to use the back-ticks at all. Just use the plain name of the bucket or field.

The back-ticks are escapes, used to allow you to refer to buckets and fields that contain characters that are not allowed by default in identifiers in N1QL. The most notable of these special characters is - (the minus sign), which is unfortunately used in Couchbase's example data sets, like beer-sample.

By default, do not use `` back ticks.